# Always recieve cannot Get /URL errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have the Cannot GET/url error when trying to load routes when running express, even though having an explicit route for each url should not be required.

I tried multiple solutions, including using an express catch all and configuring webpack

The express catch all successfully sent the index.html file, but it did not load the correct route from there. I initially assumed this was an error with react router, but this did not go away upon using a simpler node express react app. Even when copying code directly this issue still appears, and I'm unsure what else can be done.

My express catch all

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client', 'public', 'index.html'), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
        console.log("not working");
      }
    })
  })
```

My index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can anyone possibly answer this when you don't give an example of what route it fails on?  You have to make sure you provide enough details to answer the question when you ask.

Comment: I get this error for every route that doesn't have a get route written in express. When I do have an express get route, my react code fails to load. I don't know how I could be more detailed when it happens on every route.